# wrangling data from many columns to yes/no values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have seen other posts on stackoverflow, which unfortunately don't solve my issue.

I have the below dataset, which I am trying to encode:

In the end, I just want 7 columns (bread, wine, eggs, meat, cheese....), with a 1 or 0 in it, depending on whether that item was purchased.

I have tried pd.get_dummies, but it creates columns item1_bread; item2_bread... and so I cannot complete my analysis. I want to be able to have simply a 1 or 0 value in the column to say whether bread was purchased in that transaction

Can anyone help me please?

```
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7
Bread,Wine,Eggs,Meat,Cheese,Pencil,Diaper
Bread,Cheese,,Diaper,,,Pencil
Cheese,Meat,Eggs,Milk,Wine,,
Cheese,Meat,Eggs,Milk,Wine,,
Meat,Pencil,Wine,,,,
Eggs,Bread,Wine,Pencil,Milk,Diaper,Bagel
```

My desired output is like this. For each transaction, a boolean value of 1 or 0; as to whether that product existed in that transaction

```
Bread, Wine, Eggs, Meat, Cheese, Pencil, Daiper
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,0,0,0,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max` if need always `0,1` values in output:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(axis=1, level=0)
print (df1)
   Bread  Cheese  Eggs  Meat  Pencil  Wine  Diaper  Milk  Bagel
0      1       1     1     1       1     1       1     0      0
1      1       1     0     0       1     0       1     0      0
2      0       1     1     1       0     1       0     1      0
3      0       1     1     1       0     1       0     1      0
4      0       0     0     1       1     1       0     0      0
5      1       0     1     0       1     1       1     1      1
```

Or use `sum` if need count `1` values, here it is same output, in real data should be different:

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='').sum(axis=1, level=0)
print (df2)
   Bread  Cheese  Eggs  Meat  Pencil  Wine  Diaper  Milk  Bagel
0      1       1     1     1       1     1       1     0      0
1      1       1     0     0       1     0       1     0      0
2      0       1     1     1       0     1       0     1      0
3      0       1     1     1       0     1       0     1      0
4      0       0     0     1       1     1       0     0      0
5      1       0     1     0       1     1       1     1      1
```

Comment: You can also add a link to article or docs which explains `pd.get_dummies` in detail :). So that ppl can read this in detail if required.